# How do I gzip compress galleria javascript in drupal?

Tags: galleria, pagespeed

I have a Drupal 7 website that I am trying to optimize according to [this website](http://www.webpagetest.org) and I have A's for everything except "compress text" where I have a "C".  Here is what it reports:

```
GZIP encode all appropriate text assets: 79/100
119.1 KB total in compressible text, target size = 94.4 KB - potential savings = 24.7 KB

FAILED - (7.7 KB, compressed = 1.9 KB - savings of 5.8 KB) - /sites/all/libraries/galleria/themes/azur/galleria.azur.css
FAILED - (4.5 KB, compressed = 2.0 KB - savings of 2.5 KB) - /sites/all/libraries/galleria/themes/azur/galleria.azur.min.js
```

How would I configure galleria to be gzipped in a drupal environment?  I am using the boost module and some custom .htaccess rules.

Thank you!